Is a toilet flange supposed to be water tight where it meets the floor?
I had an issue recently where water from outside the toilet pooled around the base of the toilet and leaked through to the bedroom below. The toilet itself isn't leaking in the sense that there is no water from inside the toilet going outside the toilet.
I can't see under the toilet so my guess is water must've leaked through whatever gap might be between the toilet flange and the floor. Is this area supposed to be water tight?
I've read I can caulk around the base of the toilet. But I'm supposed to leave a small gap in the back so if water were ever to leak from inside the toilet to the outside I would know. However I think this gap would still allow water from outside the toilet to leak under the toilet and around the flange. But I suppose it would at least be better.
I'm debating whether or not to remove the toilet to see if I can seal the space between the flange and the floor somehow, but my main concern is making things worse given that the toilet itself isn't currently leaking.

Water is not leaking from inside the toilet, so I don't think it has anything to do with the wax seal. The toilet also does not rock. My question is regarding water leaking through the bathroom floor from the outside of the toilet.

There shouldn't normally be significant amounts of water outside the toilet...

Caulking around the base of a toilet is not intended to prevent water from leaking out from the toilet. It's primarily for appearance. The reason to leave a gap at the back is to allow water to leak out so you can see if there's a problem.

@crip659, that is the answer you should make it one

@bmaupin, if water's getting to the room below, it is leaking from the toilet. Nothing should get outside the exit path, which is the integrated trap, the wax ring, and the drain pipe.

In my area sealing or caulking the toilet to the floor is code.  I know in many places it is not.
For good measure and to prevent issues like water seeping from outside the toilet going under the base and finding its way to the ceiling downstairs,
I always caulk the toilet flange to the floor to seal it and caulk the base of the toilet.
I go further to caulk the baseboard to the floor and the base of the tub and vanity.  My goal is to prevent any water than has found it's way onto the bathroom floor from creeping under anything and causing a problem with whatever is under the bathroom.

Would a bead of caulk around the base of a toilet (except for an open section of a few inches at the back) stop a toilet from rocking?

The toilet should be set and shims used to keep it from rocking before any caulking is used.

But if the original setting of the toilet was not correct and the toilet is rocking, would a certain type of caulking (say silicone) stop the rocking? Or is the only solution to reset the toilet?

Any type of caulking should not be used for the purpose of stopping a toilet from rocking.
